# T-SQL Derived tables

Tags: t-sql

I'm relatively new to derived tables when querying in From/Join clause as I always thought that Joins would eliminate the need for these subqueries. However, my question is that when I write a subquery within an inner join, do I need to specify the **Joining column field** within the subquery select statement to initiate a Join? I know you don't usually have to do this in a normal Join, however I wrote some sql code that won't execute unless I specify the joining column in the subquery select statement (I've bolded this). I've pasted the code below.

```
select  pc.category_name
        ,product_name
        ,pp.list_price
        ,avg(quantity * (oi.list_price * (1-discount))) as Average_Revenue
        ,sum(quantity) as [products sold]
        ,sum(quantity * (oi.list_price * (1-discount))) as Revenue
        ,dt.Average_Category_Revenue
        from production.categories as pc
            inner join production.products as pp
                on pc.category_id = pp.category_id
            inner join sales.order_items as oi
                on pp.product_id = oi.product_id
            inner join (

                select  
                        category_name
                        ,**pcc.category_id**
                        ,avg(quantity * (oii.list_price * (1-discount))) as Average_Category_Revenue
                        from production.categories as pcc
                            inner join production.products as ppp
                                on pcc.category_id = ppp.category_id
                            inner join sales.order_items as oii
                                on ppp.product_id = oii.product_id
                        group by category_name, pcc.category_id
            ) as dt
                on pp.category_id = dt.category_id

        group by pc.category_name, product_name, pp.list_price, dt.Average_Category_Revenue
        order by sum(quantity * (oi.list_price * (1-discount))) DESC
```

Comment: There is no difference between joining to a table, a view, or a subquery. All three are "normal joins". All three are only possible if the joining sides both expose the fields to join on. If a field is not exposed, it does not exist for any code outside of the subquery. Just like a field not exposed from a view does not exist for anything outside of the view.

Comment: Aside: It is sometimes easier to use a common table expression (CTE) with multiple definitions as derived tables. See Example C [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#examples). You can test each definition by replacing the final `select` with one that returns data from one definition at a time. Since the query optimizer processes the whole thing as one big query there shouldn't be a performance penalty from creating something easier to write and maintain.